# Configure httpd.conf to add new site on Apache Red Hat Linux

Tags: linux, apache, httpd.conf

I have linux server (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.3 (Tikanga)) with apache installed. It is already used for browsing some documents. Now I would like to add a new Directory (with a html page), so whenever the directory is browsed it can display the html page.

But I am not sure of where all to edit the httpd.conf file

***Existing httpd.conf:***

[image]

When I hit the url "http://servername/eng" it displays list of folders.

Now, I want to add a website to this existing, so when user hit the url "http://servername/builds" it should display a html page in the browser.I have added my "index.html" page in location "/var/www/html/builds/"

For this I added the below code to **httpd.conf** file
[image]

Please let me know what all modifications are required in the conf file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in a few different ways.

1. Putting `index.html` in `/build`

   This requires you to have this setting:

   ```
   DirectoryIndex index.html
   ```

   (it should be there by default on most platform.)

   Also for this to work, rather than putting new `<Directory>`, you should put the `build/` directory in the directory that holds your `http://example.com/` files. For instance:

   ```
   /var/www/example.com/public_html/eng/
   /var/www/example.com/public_html/builds/
   /var/www/example.com/public_html/builds/index.html
   ```
2. Storing `build/` in folder completely unrelated to `example.com`, but still be able to reach it via `example.com/builds`

   For this, you need to rewrite the URLs so that `example.com/builds` redirects the user to the final URL. This is most easily achieved through mod_rewrite. You enable `mod_rewrite` module in your Apache's configuration, make sure that `example.com` can have `.htaccess` files through ensuring proper `AllowOverride` entry in `example.com`'s `<Directory>` configuration, create `/var/www//example.com/public_html/.htaccess` (or similar) file, and fill it `RewriteEngine On` and `RewriteRule`s you need. More on mod_rewrite in the Internet and in the documentation.
3. Completely separate virtual server, for example `builds.example.com/`

   In this case, what you're looking for are virtual servers. These are not defined in `httpd.conf` or configuration itself, but usually have dedicated directory.

   For example, to add `builds.example.com` that works for port 80, you'd need to create following entry:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName builds.example.com
       DocumentRoot /var/www/builds.example.com/public_html/
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

   Where to put this? Well, it depends on the platform. For Debian, you put this in a new file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`, e.g. `/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com`, and symlink to it in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` (on Debian, you can do this easily with `a2ensite <NAME_OF_FILE>`. On your platform this procedure might be different, so look it up ("adding virtual servers on " would be a start). After adding virtual servers, you need to reload your Apache configuration.

Please let me know if this satisfies your question, if not, I'll edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed explanation.As per your first point, I have added `builds` folder(with index.html) at the same place where `eng` is present.Now when I tried browsing `servername/builds` I got an error `403 Forbidden.You don't have permission to access /builds/index.html on this server.`

Comment: Are you sure Apache has access to it? (The easiest way to test it  would be to `chmod 0777` this folder. This might be wise or unwise depending on whether you're the sole user of this machine.)